# Postgres with heroku. trying to retrieve data on database

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone help me find the table name and the column name below?

```
var connectionString = "postgres://yeylegtggezrth:1909019e33185131d5efc45f37e9289ee9a7e3dfbe3814df81f2628719051273@ec2-54-83-27-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d90ti32o8t2em";
var TABLE_NAME = 'task_list';
var pg = require('pg');

var query = client.query("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(cat, item) " +
                 "values ($1, $2)", [cat, taskName]);
```

I want to know what `TABLE_NAME` name is and what columns and the name of the columns.

Comment: You ask what TABLE_NAME is after the line of code that assigns what TABLE_NAME is (`var TABLE_NAME = 'task_list'`), and this is making me think that maybe I don't understand your question after all

Comment: As per given detail table name is task_list with column name cat and item , in which your going to execute insert query.

Comment: You wrote TABLE_NAME by yourself but you wanted to know that, a bit confused it i'm not wrong